# How to trigger threads at specific system time under linux with C/C++?

Tags: c, linux

As mentioned in title, how can I execute the specific threads at specific time accurately?
Is there any library help to do it?
For example, [00:**00**:00.00, 00:**05**:00.00, 00:**10**:00.00..04:**00**:00.00, 04:**05**:00.00...]

Here is my current approach to do it, is there any better way to do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

unsigned interval = 5*60; 

void until_next_tick(time_t *last_tick){
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    time_t next_tick = now / interval * interval + interval;
    time_t diff = next_tick - now;
    usleep(diff * 1000 * 1000);
    *last_tick = next_tick;
}
void print_current_time(char *str){
    time_t raw = time(NULL);
    struct tm *curr = localtime(&raw);
    sprintf(str, "%04d/%02d/%02d %02d:%02d:%02d", 
        curr->tm_year+1900, curr->tm_mon+1, curr->tm_mday, 
        curr->tm_hour, curr->tm_min, curr->tm_sec);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    time_t last_tick = time(NULL);
    char str[30];
    while (1) {
        print_current_time(str);
        printf("%s\n", str);
        until_next_tick(&last_tick);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `the specific threads` What is specific about them? `How to trigger threads` "trigger" - in what way? Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60760338/execute-a-task-cyclic-using-posix-threads/60760811#60760811 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63773919/how-to-correctly-use-nanosleep-to-run-code-at-specific-frequency/63774221#63774221 answer your question?

Comment: What I expected is to run few number of threads like a cron job but within my C program

Answer (score 2):

Use `timer_create` with `SIGEV_THREAD` and set repeating time in `timer_settime` to start a new thread at a repeated time interval.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to have a `while(true)` loop which calls `sleep(1);` and then in the loop checks what time it is with `time(NULL)` and if the time for a thread is past due, start the corresponding thread.

Comment: This is my current approach, but I just want to know if there are any standard library help to do it.

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is using `time()` to get the time:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
void *get_sys_stat(void* arg)
{
        // Do somthing hrear
}

int main()
{
  hour = 5;
  min = 30;
  int status = 0;
  time_t t = time(NULL);
  pthread_t sys_stat_thread; 
  
  while(1) {
  /* Get time*/
  struct tm tm = *localtime(&t);
     
  /* Trigger another process or thread */  
  if ((tm.tm_hour == hour) && (tm.tm_min == min))
      pthread_create(&sys_stat_thread, NULL, get_sys_stat, NULL);
  }

}
```